# Big TBT and FCP variations on similar pages

Tags: pagespeed

We're seeing much worse TBT and LCP scores on a couple of our most-read pages compared to other pages on our site, despite everything being nearly identical except the text. How is that possible? And why would those scores remain static over weeks after being in flux prior. Our LCP has been stuck at 74% good, just below a passing grade.

Our internal TBT scores are about .3s, but Google is showing as high as 1.5s on some pages.